# Rearranging an equation that shows two circles

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am supposed to sketch $M\subseteq\mathbb{C}$

$M$ is definded by the following condition $\left(4Re\left(z\right)\right)^2-\left|z\right|^4\ge0$

From rearranging the inequality I derive

$$-16x^2+x^4+2x^2\cdot y^2+y^4\le0$$

I know that the picture of the subset I am looking for is two circles. So this equation must be rearranged (partly using quadratic addition) in a way that it resembles

$$\left(x-m_x\right)^2+\left(y-m_y\right)^2=r^2$$

But what will this general equation look like if its graph shows two circles? 
Could it be that I am going the wrong way and I actually need to find two equations doing a case analysis somewhere?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So $|z|^{2}\leq 4|\text{Re}(z)|$, with $z=a+bi$, then $a^{2}+b^{2}\leq 4|a|$, if $a\geq 0$, $(a-2)^{2}+b^{2}\leq 4$, if $a<0$, then $(a+2)^{2}+b^{2}\leq 4$.